# Google Drive API JavaScript - Insert file

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I'm trying to "insert" a Drive file.
I've made the auth and it works right :)

But when I try to create (insert) a new file from JS, it creates one, but a file named "Untitled" with no extension at all. (I have a sync folder on my file system, and it is the same thing).

My code is this:

```
 function createNewFile(  ) {
    gapi.client.load('drive', 'v2', function() {
    var request = gapi.client.drive.files.insert ( {
        "title" : "cat.jpg",
        "mimeType" : "image/jpeg",
        "description" : "Some"
        } );
    request.execute(function(resp) { console.log(resp); });
    });
 }
```

Any idea about what is wrong?
I can list files from my drive from JS, and this code creates this "untitled" and no extensioned file.

Comment: i dont have 1500 points, so i cannot create a new tag on stackOverflow, it is "google-drive-api" instead of google-drive-sdk, but it doesn't exist yet

Comment: There is no need for a new tag here, we already have *two* to cover Google Drive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have that working like this:

```
function createNewFile(  ) {

    gapi.client.load('drive', 'v2', function() {

       var request = gapi.client.request({
        'path': '/drive/v2/files',
        'method': 'POST',
        'body':{
            "title" : "cat.jpg",
            "mimeType" : "image/jpeg",
            "description" : "Some"
         }
     });

      request.execute(function(resp) { console.log(resp); });
   });
}
```

Bear in mind that if a file with title `cat.jpg` already exists, this request will create another file with the same title, since files in Google Drive have unique file IDs by which are referred internally.

Comment: 'var request = gapi.client.request({'   That line was the problem!! Thank you very much!

Comment: I wonder why Google documentation mentions the 'files.insert' function when they don't use it in the examples.

Comment: Can we check if folder exits or not in Google drive by name?