# Create new Google Drive file with text content (javascript)

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I can use javascript Google API to authentifie my webapp and create new file in Google Drive, as it's explained [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11280381/google-drive-api-javascript-insert-file) :

```
function createNewFile() {
    gapi.client.load('drive', 'v2', function() {
        var request = gapi.client.request({
            'path': '/drive/v2/files',
            'method': 'POST',
            'body':{
                "title" : "test.txt",
                "description" : "Some"
            }
        });
        request.execute(function(resp) { console.log(resp); });
    });
}
```

It creates an empty file in Drive. But I don't know how to create a new non-empty file by adding text content to it (for example "blablabla"). Can someone please help me ?

Comment: Have a loot at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10330992/authorization-of-google-drive-using-javascript/10331393#10331393).

Answer (score 2):

Checkout the update function I made for updating a file after insert  [How do I add/create/insert files to Google Drive through the API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10317638/inserting-file-to-google-drive-through-api/13985931#13985931)

Read the the main answer on the page, this also hints to create/insert in one call to the API.