# Google Drive files meta data read

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-drive-api

I am trying to get the google drive selected images displayed on my webapp using Google Picker. In order to get the webcontent of image, I need to read the metadata. However I am getting an error that is something like this

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of undefined localhost:169
printFile localhost:169
pickerCallback localhost:156
K.Ld default.I.js:103
_.zc cb=gapi.loaded_0:57
_.Ib
```

Here is the code that I am using

```
    function printFile(fileId) {
    var request = gapi.client.drive.files.get({
        'fileId': fileId

        });
      request.execute(function(resp) {
        console.log('Title: ' + resp.title);
        console.log('Description: ' + resp.description);
        console.log('MIME type: ' + resp.mimeType);
      });
     }
```

Once I get the metadata of images I will use Webcontent for image display on webapp but its just not getting the metadata. Please tell me how to fix this error.

Answer (score 5):

Got it working using another piece of code which is:

```
    function printFile(fileId) {
    var theID = fileId;
    var request = gapi.client.request({
        'path': '/drive/v2/files/'+theID,
            'method': 'GET',
        });
      request.execute(function(resp) {
        console.log('Title: ' + resp.title);
        console.log('Description: ' + resp.description);
        console.log('MIME type: ' + resp.mimeType);
        console.log('WebContent: ' + resp.webContentLink);
             });
    }
```